# Continue running tests in Xcode when a test crashes

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

When running a large suite of tests within Xcode, I came across the a test that crashed. The Xcode debugger showed the location of the crash, however there didn't seem to be anyway to mark that test as failed and keep running the rest of the tests.

How within Xcode to mark a crashed test as failed and keep running the rest of the tests?

Comment: I know its been 3 years since OP's question but nevertheless, what **@Jason Harrison** meant is that, if you are running unit tests from Xcode, once a crash occurs, all you have to do is select "Debug" from the Xcode's menu bar at the top and select "Detach from SampleTests" (SampleTests is the name of your test target), so that the debugger will continue with the rest of your tests and the test case that caused the crash will be marked as a failure with a red cross, stating "Test Crashed" as the failure message. Adding this as an answer instead of a comment because I have only 40 rep and coul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest, and possibly, only way to mark a crashed test as failed and keep running the rest of the tests is to use Debug > Detach to let the crashed test "die". Xcode will continue to run the remaining tests.

Comment: What do you mean with use Debug>Detach, could you provide some details please?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use this: https://marcosantadev.com/test-swift-fatalerror/

It's a little bit tricky but it works.